# Incorrect chart displayed using chart js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js, yii2-basic-app

I am using XAMPP web server.

I have created folder chartexample in htdocs.

Now I want to display database data using chart js.

So I created data.php and bargraph.html files into chartexample folder. Similarly I created app.js file in js folder in chartexample folder.

But when I run this code undefined is display on chart. Below are my code :

data.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "shgreportingdatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";



$sql = "SELECT employee.FirstName, count(*) as TotalGroups from groupdetails, employee WHERE groupdetails.EmpId=employee.EmpId group by groupdetails.EmpId";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result!=null) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       print json_encode($row);
    }
} 
$conn->close();
```

Here is bargraph.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #chart-container {
                width: 640px;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>


        <!-- javascript -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartexample/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var emp = [];
            var groups = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                emp.push(data[i].FirstName);
                groups.push(data[i].FirstName);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: emp,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'SHG Groups',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: groups
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you getting the data you want in `console.log(data);` from your ajax success callback?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT employee.FirstName, count(*) as TotalGroups from groupdetails, employee WHERE groupdetails.EmpId=employee.EmpId group by groupdetails.EmpId";
```

In the above, you're using `WHERE` to specify a link between two tables. This is a job for `JOIN`. You also need to specify something concrete in `WHERE` unless you want to get all the rows.

```
$SQL = "SELECT employee.FirstName, count(*) as 'TotalGroups' FROM groupdetails g JOIN employee e ON g.EmpId = e.EmpId
```

If you need to use a `WHERE` in there to exclude some data, you'll need to specify the table. For example, `WHERE g.id = 5` to return ID 5 from the groupdetails table.

If you *do* want to return all rows, omit the `WHERE` clause altogether.

Comment: I replaced the SQL as you provided, but still not working